# Docker Elasticsearch Bulk index timeout

Tags: elasticsearch, docker

I am running Elasticsearch 2.3 using the docker official builds. I am trying to bulk index a fairly large dataset. The dataset in question is abotu 700mb and on a non dockerized setup takes around 30 minutes. Around 24 hours ago I started the bulk index operation on the docker elasticsearch container. As of yet it still hasn't completed, worse there is no load on the server which indicates it's not even attempting to index.

I know the bulk indexing works because I can index a smaller dataset and it works without a problem.

Is there any specific settings that I need to be aware of when indexing data over a certain size? or any way to check why it errored?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any future people reading this, firstly Hello from the past!

Secondly, elasticsearch has a default bulk maximum size of 100mb so make sure you're requests (including posted files) are below that